# Script to hang up Asterisk channels

Tags: shell-script, awk, asterisk

I am trying to create a script for Asterisk. We use a lot of channspy. Sometimes the channspy stays opened and didn't hangup even if the softphone is hangup (I don't understand why).
So I thought of creating a script to take the number of channels opened started with the `SIP/[extension]-channel` and this grep export it to a `TXT` file this file will have 3 columns and extract just the first column with

```
awk ' {print $1} '
```

but here is where I stuck because each row has 1 channel and if I want to hangup this channel I have to do

```
asterisk -rx 'soft hangup SIP/[exntesion]-channel'
```

Can someone help me with this to get each row as a variable and loop the script till the last row.
so the command will be something like

```
asterisk -rx 'soft hangup $variable'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can use `system` with awk:

```
awk ' command = "asterisk -rx '\''soft hangup " $1 "'\''" { system(command); }' channels_file
```

just for testing:

```
awk ' command = "asterisk -rx '\''soft hangup " $1 "'\''" { print command; }' channels_file
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat 3-column-file-of-yours.txt | awk '{ sprintf "asterisk -rx \'soft hangup SIP/%s-channel\'\n",$1; }' | /bin/bash`

Play with number of slashes near \' if you'll have trouble with the string and feel free to ask questions!

Comment: Seems like the command is not terminated it gors to another line that starts with > and then empty can't understand the os is cent os.

Comment: can you please attach an example file and the command output you need to hangup - I'll debug it and post here